# Crystal Reports Calculate Summary

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-server

I have 2 fields ITEMID and QTYSOLD, I need to get a total for each ITEMID from the QTYSOLD.

However when running this query it shows each and every ITEMID and QTY sold. For example

```
ITEMID QTYSOLD
QEE123             3<br>
QEE123            10
                  <br>
                  **13**

HEE123             3
<br>
HEE123            20<br>
                  **23**
```

---

I need it to show

```
QEE123 13
HEE    23
```

I have tried to supress the ITEMID and QTYSOLD if theres a duplicate however it then only calculates the first entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Group by `ITEMID` and place `QTYSOLD` in detail part.
2. Now you take the summary of `QTYSOLD` in group footer of `ITEMID` and supress detail part. and place `ITEMID` to the extreme left of group footer.

Comment: Thanks @Siva, This now works. However the White space is massive I presume due to the surpress. Can you advise how to reduce this.

Comment: normally you don't get any white space when supress... can you post the screenshot.. so that I can advice

Comment: Under the details Section, I just supressed that entire selection and that solved it. Thank you !